# Converting AGE column to numeric and create a histogram

Tags: r, histogram

I'm trying to create a Histogram from AGE column but I can't do that as its class is a Factor.

**The thing is** my values are AGE is written like this: "less than 20", "21 to 35", "36 to 50", "51 and more".

So, I needed to convert them to numeric values and I used these functions

```
AGE_num <- as.numeric(AGE)
```

Then, I've got 1, 2, 3, 4 names for above values.
Next I tried to rename them from "2" to "21-35" or even to just "21".

```
AGE_num[AGE_num == "2"] <- "35"

AGE_num[AGE_num == "3"] <- "50"

AGE_num[AGE_num == "1"] <- "100"

AGE_num[AGE_num == "4"] <- "20"*
```

After renaming like this my AGE column again becomes factor and I still Can't to do a histogram ...
Please, anyone could you assist me in this.
Big thanks in advance! 
(I'm a Beginner in R)

Comment: How did you created the `AGE` column?

Comment: If your data is already in 4 bins, a histogram won't be appropriate. Try `barplot` instead.

Comment: Are you changing values `less than 20` to 20?

Comment: Hi hi! thanks for your activity!

Comment: Akrun, actually I downloaded dataset from the kaggle, and there column AGE is already was in that form. In description is says that AGE is categorical.

Comment: barplot? never heard before. Okay I will try

Comment: Yes, I tried to change variables, but still I get errors...

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/ydalat/lifestyle-and-wellbeing-data 
here is a link to my dataset that I'm working on.